# Will fastboot not proceed with flashing if battery level is below certain percentage?

Tags: battery, 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-nexus-s, fastboot

I'm trying to re-install Clockwork recovery mod (tl;dr: Android 2.3.1+ will reinstall stock recovery on every boot if it's not present).

I had installed it successfully yesterday, but today it does not go beyond

```
C:\android>tools\fastboot.exe flash recovery NexusS\kernel\recovery-clockwork-3.0.0.5-crespo.img
< waiting for device >
```

The only difference would be that today the battery level is low ( currently at 20% and charging).

So does fastboot require the battery to be over a set level ?

Comment: I can't find any info on this, but it's a good rule of thumb to have a well-charged battery before flashing anything.  You should also try rebooting your device and PC and try again, sometimes it just doesn't take when the device is in an odd state.

Comment: Agreeing with Matthew. I wouldn't flash anything with a low battery.

Comment: @MatthewRead Thanks, I've rebooted my device & PC but to no effect.

Comment: Thanks @Bryan I'll wait till it gets charged and will post back.

Comment: looking through the source of fastboot, I do not see anything that would suggest that the battery has to be a certain percent, although, like Matthew Read said, I wouldn't attempt it with a sub 50% charged battery.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was not in fastboot mode :| (yes, terrible mistake). I was able to flash after getting into fastboot mode.